# How to find the leak in a basement?

Tags: repair, basement, leak

There is a leak in my basement as you can see in the picture below, probably close to the roof of the basement as I've highlighted in my picture.

[image]

Question:

- How can I find that leak, knowing I cannot spot it?

PS: Should I mention , the basement's roof is close to a rain gutter. Each time it is raining, the water drops close to that basement and the leak/hole is making the basement wet and sometimes flooded (when raining heavily).

Update: This is what stand above , on the corner where the leak is happening

[image]

Comment: Is the other side of that block wall entirely below grade? What is directly above that corner?

Comment: hi @brhans please see my update. What do you mean by `entirely below grade`?

Answer (score 1):

I can see some cracks in the cement at the top of the drain. it looks like the drain is full of debris is it draining properly? If the drain is plugged or partially obstructed the water may be backing up enough and flowing through the cracks. Sealing the cracks with hydraulic cement (outside the house) will reduce the amount of water escaping the box and that should reduce the water entering the basement. Make sure to seal the cracks all the way to the bottom if they extend that far down I cant tell in the photo.